# Trying to search a number from multiple sql tables with identical structures

Tags: sql-server

Trying to search a number from multiple sql tables with identical structures , here is what I am trying to do `select a, b, c from table_a, table_b, table_c where a = '12344'`

the result could be from either of the one tables.

its giving us this error

> ambiguous column name

Answer (score 1):

On your query :
for multiple table having same column name, you need to specify the table name plus the column name. Instead of just a, you need to specify it like `table_a.a = '12344'`

On your requirement :
You should be searching 1 table at a time and use UNION ALL

```
SELECT a, b, c, from table_a where a = '12344'
union all
SELECT a, b, c, from table_b where a = '12344'
union all
SELECT a, b, c, from table_c where a = '12344'
```

Comment: Thanks ... !!! Is there some way by which we could search a value in the first table if not found then second and then third ?  The table names are different but the structure and column name are same .. :(

Comment: then you will have split into individual query. use @@rowcount to check for any result of 1st query. If @@rowcount = 0 then perform 2nd query and so on. You may also need to use temp table to store the result of each query and then return as one result at the end

Comment: Thank you guys .. Here is my query now however I wish to know how can i search multiple values like we do with where a in ('123','321','432') declare @@cp varchar(20) set @cp = '123' SELECT a, b, c, from table_a where a = @@cp
union all
SELECT a, b, c, from table_b where a =@@cp
union all
SELECT a, b, c, from table_c where a = @@cp

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have three tables in `select` and you did not qualify your columns used. I guess you are looking for this

Use `UNION ALL`

```
select a from table_a where a = '12344'
UNION ALL
select b from  table_b where a = '12344'
UNION ALL
select c from  table_c where a = '12344'
```

or Another way using `join`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table_a ta 
       CROSS JOIN table_b tb 
       CROSS JOIN table_c tc 
WHERE  '12344' IN ( ta.a, tb.a, tc.a )
```

**Note :** Both the queries will have result set in different format. Also keep in mind that you are doing a Cartesian product of three tables.

Comment: Thanks ... !!! Is there some way by which we could search a value in the first table if not found then second and then third ?  The table names are different but the structure and column name are same .. :(

Comment: Thank you guys .. Here is my query now however I wish to know how can i search multiple values like we do with where a in ('123','321','432') declare @@cp varchar(20) set @cp = '123' SELECT a, b, c, from table_a where a = @@cp union all SELECT a, b, c, from table_b where a =@@cp union all SELECT a, b, c, from table_c where a = @@cp